# Nifi Moving files on HDFS path for the previous day merged json file

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, mapr, data-ingestion

I have a requirement to move the previous day processed and merged json files into new hdfs path. The requirement is to recursively search unprocessed files and move the pending unprocessed files.

Path 1 -> /data/nifi/working/2019/10/source_2019_10_15.json --- Daily processed files are merged under this path and gets added on daily basis.
Path 2 -> /data/nifi/incoming/ -- The code should search if folders doesn’t exist then create and move the files are just move the files if the folders are already present.

Currently, I am using nifi flow -- ListHDFS->MoveHDFS but unable to achieve it.

Need help how this can be achieved.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution and if so do you recall how you did resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The current flow worked fine.

listhdfs->fethchdfs->updateattribute->puthdfs

In the listhdfs, set the minimum file age wait time before consuming. This will allow the process to search files recursively and also use updateattribute to re-create the folder as and process file into /data/nifi/incoming/.